# Re-run script in Python 3.5

Tags: python

How do I get `main` to run again without executing the whole script again?

```
import sys #importing module that is used to exit the script

def main ():

#doing stuff

main ()

#Re-run the script - looking for a cleaner way to do this!

def restart ():

    restart = input("Press any key + Enter to start again, or x + Enter to exit.")
    if(restart != "x"):
            exec(open("./calc.py").read())
            # not sure how to run main() again without calling out the script name again?
    else:
            print ("Exiting!")
    sys.exit ((main))

restart ()

#End of Program
```

Comment: Just... call `main()` again? But why are you `exec`ing anything?

Comment: Because the OP's original post stated they are just starting programming/python and they're learning =)

Answer (score 0):

You can re-run the `main` module-method as many times as you want by directly calling `main()` sequentially:

```
def main( ):
   # Code goes here...
   return;

main();
main();
main();
```

However, if you want the user-interaction like your restart method has, you might want to consider defining `main` with an optional parameter (one that has a default value) that controls whether you ask to re-run the method or not.

```
def main( argv, AskRestart= True ):

   # Main code goes here....

   if ( AskRestart ):
       # User interaction code goes here ...

   return;
```

Also, you can look into the `atexit` package in Python 3.5.1 to see how you can assign a method to be run only when exiting the interpreter:
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/atexit.html

That would allow you to do whatever you want and then when everything is done, give someone the option of restarting the entire module. This would remove the reliance on the `exec` call, and be a more coherent and simpler approach to getting the exact same expected functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the help - greatly appreciated. But replacing exec (... with main() only lets it run twice then exits out? I tried to get argv to work to no avail so far, but I will keep trying/

Comment: As I said above, you want to update your main method with an optional argument, and then instead of exec, you update your restart method so that it calls main with a value of `True` or `False` for the `AskRestart` parameter. If you then use `atexit` (see documentation at link above) to assign `restart` as the atexit method that gets run, then you'll get it `main` called again through restart. If you want it to potentially "restart" forever, don't use `atexit`, just have restart call main with `AskRestart` set properly, and in the `if (AskRestart)` call `restart` again to be semi-recursive.

Comment: Oh okay, got it. Thank you Again for your help and being patient!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tommy's great advice, (I'm not sure of your goal in continually restarting main() as main is an empty function that doesn't do anything yet, but..) one way to have main continually repeat until the user enters `x` may be to use a `while True` loop:

```
import sys #importing module that is used to exit the script                                        

def main ():

#doing stuff                                                                                        

    restart() # <-- use main to restart()

#Re-run the script - looking for a cleaner way to do this!                                          

def restart ():

    restart = raw_input("Press any key + Enter to start again, or x + Enter to exit.")
    while True:     # <-- key to continually restart main() function
        if(restart != "x"):
            exec(open("./calc.py").read())
        # not sure how to run main() again without calling out the script name again?               
            main()   # <-- restart main
        else:
            print ("Exiting!")
        sys.exit ((main))

restart ()

#End of Program
```

Hope this also helps!

Comment: Worked Great! Thank You All Again!